# How can i execute the action only on the div,when i have multiple div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseenter

How can i execute the action only on the div,when i have multiple div with same class

http://jsfiddle.net/kent93/Qw7bw/

when the mouse enter one div , the other div also will have action , how can i solve this

i want only the div that my mouse goes in take action , not the other, what best solution?

Comment: to Dale Burrell : if use unique class or id,there is a problem which is when later time i add another div , then i have to manually add the corresponding javascript as well, it is not efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the selector of each position to:  `$(this).children(".class")`

for example the code `$(".fromTopToBottom")` will change to  `$(this).children(".fromTopToBottom")`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qw7bw/10/

Answer (score 2):

very simple, use $(this), for example

```
$('.mydivclass').mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).css('color','gray'); // Current element
});
```

If divs are nested then you should use e.stopPropagation() to stop the event bubling.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a "current" div concept.

1. At the beginning of mouseenter handler:

   $(".trbl").removeClass("current");
   $(this).addClass("current");
2. In your case statement, `$(".fromTopToBottom").css({...})` -> `$(".current .fromTopToBottom").css({...})`

For the effect check out http://jsfiddle.net/Qw7bw/7/

Comment: you're genius , your way make every thing so amazingly efficient, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this).find(x) rather than $(x) directly when selecting ".fromTopToBottom" and similar classes. This allows jQuery to only select childs of the hovered element http://jsfiddle.net/Qw7bw/6/

Comment: nice , your way is find something inside a current div, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).children(".fromTopToBottom")` instead of `$(".fromTopToBottom")`.

This will select divs of the given class inside the element whose handler you are writing.