# In JQuery, how to only perform the action on the current div of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

The html is like this:

```
<div class="a_list">
  <div class="hide_list_scrollbar"></div>
</div>
<div class="a_list">
  <div class="hide_list_scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

The js is like this:

```
$(".a_list").mouseenter(
    function(){
        $(".hide_list_scrollbar").hide();
    }
);
$(".a_list").mouseleave(
    function(){
        $(".hide_list_scrollbar").show();
    }
);
```

Right now, the mouse event is performed on all the "a_list" divs. I only want to perform the mouse event on the particular div that actually activated the mouse event, not all of the "a_list" divs. How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: A very similar question was answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952512/how-can-i-execute-the-action-only-on-the-div-when-i-have-multiple-div-with-same?rq=1

Comment: Hello Matt, sorry I actually read that question during my search, but couldn't figure out what I had to do. I'm a total noob at js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a context to the selector. See below,

```
$(".hide_list_scrollbar", this).hide();
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(".a_list").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".hide_list_scrollbar", this).hide();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".hide_list_scrollbar", this).show();
});
```

Or you can use `.find` like below,

```
$(".a_list").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".hide_list_scrollbar").hide();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".hide_list_scrollbar").show();
});
```

**Note:** I have chained your call to reduce the query to DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to `this` which will be the object in question (finding only the `.hide_list_scrollbar` class within the div that triggered the event.):

```
$(".a_list").mouseenter(
    function(){
        $(".hide_list_scrollbar", this).hide();
    }
);
$(".a_list").mouseleave(
    function(){
        $(".hide_list_scrollbar", this).show();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think yours is correct too, but you are just 1 minute later than the other one, so I'm going to have to accept the other answer, sorry.

Comment: Win some, lose some. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned, use `this` as the context to reference the element that triggered that event. Then you could find the `hide_list_scrollbar` div within that element and hide/show it. 
Also, i would use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) as it's a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$(".a_list").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.hide_list_scrollbar').hide();
    }, 
    function(){ 
        $(this).find('.hide_list_scrollbar').show(); 
    }
);
```